# Android toLeftOf and toRightOf not working strange behavior

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I want to place an `EditText` between 2 images...

Normally, it works perfect but I don't know why it is not working now...

I put first both images in the `RelativeLayout` and than add the `EditText`...

Screenhot:

[image: Screenshot]

Could you check my code ?

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/search_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:elevation="3dp"
    android:visibility="invisible">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_navigation_arrow_back"
        android:id="@+id/search_view_back"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_navigation_close"
        android:id="@+id/search_view_delete"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/font"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:hint="@string/contact_search_hint"
        android:textColorHint="#607a7a71"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/search_view_back"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/search_view_delete"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
        android:id="@+id/search_view_input"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: On what version of Android are you testing?

Comment: You have `android:visibility="invisible"` in the `RelativeLayout`. If it isn't showing up at all...

Comment: Screenshot is added.

Android 5.1.1

And visibility is set to visible programmaticly ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if i were you i would use LinearLayout instead of RelativeLayout in this cases.
You can use the "layout_weight" property for this kind of situations.anyway i tried a little xml for your case.try it and let me know mate

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"  tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
         />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" /></LinearLayout>
```